# Listbox is one userobject and singlelineedit in other userobject

Tags: powerbuilder

How to add data from single line edit to Listbox that is i am created single line edit in one userobject and listbox in another userobject.when ever i enter data in singlelineedit and click add button that data had to be add in listbox.

Answer (score 1):

The basic answer to your question (and applicable if the userobjects you speak of are standard visual userobjects) is:

```
lb.AddItem (sle.text)
```

If the userobjects are custom visual userobjects, then the answer becomes much more complex, and depends on the relationship of the UOs (e.g. are they siblings, both placed on the same window, or is one inside the other, or...) and on your philosophy of encapsulation and coding practices. In general, I'd suggest creating top-level events and functions for communications into and out of the userobject, and wire connections between userobjects at the container level. However, more than that, it's for complexities like this that I'd discourage people from using custom visual userobjects.

Good luck,

Terry

Comment: I'd use a DataWindow and let them type directly in the "list".